# Голова садовая

Tags: фразеология

"Голова садовая" - так говорят о о ком-то или чаще о себе, когда имеют в виду, что что-то не сообразил, до чего-то не додумался или что-то забыл.
А почему, собственно, садовая? Это как-то связано со словом "сад"? Но, если так, честно говорят, не могу сообразить, каким образом?
Буду благодарно за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видел две версии: это выражение сравнивает голову человека либо с головой пугала, либо с кочаном капусты. И то, и другое очевидно связано с садом (огородом). Мне кажется более вероятным сравнение с кочаном, соответствующая цитата классика:

> > - Это людям-то помогать вредно? -- с задором спросил Фома.
> >        --  Эх,  **голова  садовая**,  то  есть  --  **капуста**!  --  сказал Маякин  с
> >   улыбочкой.

Answer (score 0):

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/17201385

Answer (score 0):

1 версия. Первоначально о пугале в виде человека в огороде, саду.
2. Головой (в саду, огороде) называли (да и сейчас называют) капустный кочан.

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму , чего все так прицепились к *саду*-*огороду* . Это всё равно , что искать ночью , там , где фонарь горит , а не там , где потерял . Привели даже какую-то литературную цитату с указанием на капусту , - *народную этимологию* не надо безоговорочно ставить на место истинной . Насколько я знаю , словосочетание **ГОЛОВА САДОВАЯ** употребляется для характеристики человека , в смысле **этакий**-**разэтакий** . Давайте поищем этимологию в иврите , - ИРИС-словарь д-ра Баруха Подольского /интернет-ссылка [Ирис-словарь.](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php)/ . Ивритное **שד** **шед** буквы *шин*/*син* и *далет* /внимание : читать справа-налево !/ в переводе означает **чёрт** , **бес** . Ивритная **ש** *шин*/*син* озвучивается двояко , как **Ш** и **С** . Так что может быть и **ШЕД** И **СЕД** . (*Например , евреи-ефремиты , которые ещё до н. э. заселили Балканы известны тем , что , вообще , не проговаривали Ш , а только С ; существует предание , как во время одной междоусобицы беглецов-ефремитов распознавали , заставляя произнести слово "шиболет" .*)  Гласных букв в классическом иврите , как таковых , нет , и в диалектной огласовке возможны вариации , - это **שד**  может быть и **шад** и означать женскую грудь . Ниже , я поместил скриншот из ИРИС-словаря , - смотрите там значение и чтение . Таким образом , совершенно очевидно , что в словосочетании **ГОЛОВА САДОВАЯ** корень **САД** означает **ЧЁРТ** , **БЕС** . То есть , в буквальном смысле **ЧЁРТОВА ГОЛОВА** . Вообще , в русской разговорной речи *евреизмов* немеряно , - **ГОЛОВА САДОВАЯ** это один из них , первоисходный смысл  которого со временем просто забылся .  =============================================================================  [image: шед/сад - чёрт , бес .]